# Workers’ compensation in Halacha

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, employment, torts-damages, injury

In secular law, there is something called [workers’ compensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workers%27_compensation), which basically means that employers are obligated to pay for their employees who get injured/sick on the job. This is done to help workers who’re injured while protecting employers  from general liability. My question is, excluding Dina D’malchuta Dina, does an equivalent exist in Halacha?

Comment: Even if not, it could be stipulated

Comment: Continued salary for sick workers is discussed in Bava Metzia 77a-b, which implies that even if you've hired someone for a full day they won't receive pay for the ill time. However some opinions will apply exceptions...

Comment: ...that said, all this applies when workers have a fixed term contract lasting over the time of the illness (and even so they probably don't get paid) - if the contract can be terminated at will obviously they wouldn't be covered